# How to handle long numbers when exporting to excel from datatables.net

Tags: datatables

Our company folks have been struggling for many days now to handle long numbers being exported as exponent values into excel.

we came across a few solutions but didn't work for us.

any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The typical way is for you to ask your question as a self contained question  and then you can answer it yourself at the same time with the appropriate answer. This maintains the required Stack Overflow Q&A format. The current Q+A in the same Question is a bad fit and will be deleted. Please consider revising as suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

After much expoloring we found a lead. the article about [excelHtml5 Customisation](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5#Customisation) on datatables.net website gave us an idea.

we added following code under exportOptions section of the datatables.net definition:

```
customize: function (xlsx) {
        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
        
        $('row:gt(1) c[r^="B"]', sheet).each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('s');
        $(this).attr('t', 'inlineStr');
        $(this).find('v').replaceWith('<is><t>' + $(this).text() + '</t></is>');
    });
}
```

the trick is to replace the xml tags/attributes for numbers with tags for text.

- **row:gt(1)** is used to start from second row
- **c[r^="B"]** is used to target the column. in this case it is 'B'

Enjoy!